# Access denied cmd C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, cmd, process

Im trying to make a backup trigger inside my C# project and im stuck at making command execute. I can do this manually and its the same as in here but somehow when I try to implement it inside C# project I cant run it (can but it says "Access denied").

```
string cmdKomanda = @"/k cd C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin" + Environment.CurrentDirectory+ @"pg_dump -h 192.168.130.240 -p 5433 -U postgres  -F c  postgres > ""C:\Users\Marko Petričević\Documents\Radni_sati_Backup\radni_sati_15_01_18"" " + Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"password";
        ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =new ProcessStartInfo("CMD.exe", cmdKomanda);
        Process.Start(procStartInfo);
```

Basically first I have to come to PostgreSQL bin folder to run pg_dumb from there. After I run that command, password is needed.

Runtime value of cmdKomanda is:

```
"/k cd C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.6\\binC:\\Users\\Marko Petričević\\Desktop\\TortoiseSVN\\Radni_sati-Dev\\Radni_sati\\bin\\Debugpg_dump -h 192.168.130.240 -p 5433 -U postgres  -F c  postgres > C:\\\\Users\\\\Marko Petričević\\\\Documents\\\\Radni_sati_Backup\\\\radni_sati_15_01_18 C:\\Users\\Marko Petričević\\Desktop\\TortoiseSVN\\Radni_sati-Dev\\Radni_sati\\bin\\Debugpassword"
```

Comment: What is the value of `cmdKomanda` at runtime? `Environment.CurrentDirectory` is not what you want there.

Comment: there are so many possible reasons why this might not work, that you at least need to show us the error you get.

Comment: @SebastianL there are no errors. Just "Access denied." and path is returned where the project is located.

Comment: @MarkoPetričević have you tried to run it as admin?

Comment: _I cant run it._ What happens when you try?

Comment: does that path really look correct to you? Look closely.

Comment: @Crowcoder The path that I use there is the one I use manually for testing. Only difference are quotations that I use before and after path ( I use them manually too, because in path there are spaces in name of some folders). They are just doubled inside C#.

Comment: you have `c:` in there twice

Comment: @MarkoPetričević look at that path string it is obviously an invalid path. READ it letter by letter. Environment.CurrentDirectory returns a fully qualified path.

Comment: @Crowcoder ok, maybe ur right. Maybe the string is wrong. Then tell me how would you write down a string that has for ex. "test one" folder in path (when there is space in name of folder)?

Comment: The problem I am trying to explain has nothing to do with spaces. You must quote paths that contain spaces but that will not solve all your problems.

Comment: @Crowcoder Ok, but then give me a solution please, not a riddle =)

Comment: I don't know how to explain it better. Paste that path into windows explorer and see what happens. You can't use a path that is not a valid path.

Comment: @Crowcoder I really do understand what are you trying to say. But try to understand what im saying. If I copy: `"C:\Users\Marko Petričević\Documents\Radni_sati_Backup"` to windows explorer It wont open anything, but thats how you write something to cmd.exe when there are spaces in folder name. So if I dont use quatitions it will open that directory. But problem starts when I have to implement quatations to C# project. Its a string and every string is defined by "". So if I want to put another pair of quatitions I have to put double ones. So I understand what are you saying but...

Comment: I'm only commenting about how your are combining two paths together to form an invalid path. That is why it is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @Crowcoder Yea, I understand that now, from the answer below. But separating it is still not the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, looks like I cant use pg_dump.exe, and command has to start with /k

```
 var cmdKomanda = @"/k pg_dump -h 192.168.130.240 -p 5433 -U postgres  -F c  postgres >""C:\Users\Marko Petričević\Documents\Radni_sati_Backup\radni_sati_proba"" ";
        ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("CMD.exe", cmdKomanda);
        procStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin";
        procStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["PGPASSWORD"] = sifra; // pg_dump 
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        Process.Start(procStartInfo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to emulate an interactive session with `cd` and entering password, use facilities of `ProcessStartInfo` to set working folder an to pass `PGPASSWORD`:

```
var cmdKomanda = @"-h 192.168.130.240 -p 5433 -U postgres  -F c  postgres > ""C:\Users\Marko Petričević\Documents\Radni_sati_Backup\radni_sati_15_01_18""";
ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =new ProcessStartInfo("pg_dump.exe", cmdKomanda);
procStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin";
procStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["PGPASSWORD"] = password; // pg_dump will pick it up
```

Comment: I like the way you make this work, but the only thing it does is open working directory in cmd, somehow like he doesnt execute command (saw in folder, no created files). 

P.S. I had to put

    `procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            Process.Start(procStartInfo);`

Comment: @MarkoPetričević Could you try running `pg_dump.exe` without using cmd at all?

Comment: I could, but that would open PGadmin 4 for me. I dont want to use PGadmin everytime I want to make a backup, if you know what I mean.